# How to save and then retrieve all window variables in JS?

Tags: javascript

the JS script uses: `window.opener.variables` since variables are stored on the windows that opened the popup.

My goal is to avoid to use the popup, but keep the script as it is.

Idea1: I try to save the window object into localStorage and retrieve it

```
localStorage.setItem('win', window)
```

and the use

```
window.opener = localStorage.getItem('win')
```

Problem : localStorage.setItem('win', window) does not save the global variables.

Looks like Object.keys(window) can help here... but no idea how to store its values.

Comment: you cannot serialize everything from window.

Comment: Sounds like an XY issue. Why would you _want_ to store `window` in its entirety?

Comment: because the JS scripts uses tons of window.opener.xxxxx variables !

Comment: Why are you using `localStorage` ? Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Any progress ?? please let me know if some how you achieve this.